# How to generate Ethereum wallets(private/public keys) for users using PHP/JS?

Tags: javascript, php, blockchain, ethereum

I need to generate Ethereum wallets for each user of my site. I need to get private and public keys. How to do it using PHP or Javascript?
For Ethereum I found web3.js library which I can use for getting access to an ethereum nodes, but I see examples only for checking balances or sending transactions for existed wallets. How to create them from begging with no private/public keys at all?

Comment: The easiest way to generate an ETH private key in PHP is `$private = \random_bytes( 32 );`

Comment: See also: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated

Answer (score 3):

Try to use "web3.eth.accounts" in web3js

`web3.eth.accounts.create();`

See more: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#create

Or try to use PHP with web3.php

```
newAccount = '';

$web3->personal->newAccount('123456', function ($err, $account) use(&$newAccount) {
    if ($err !== null) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $err->getMessage();
        return;
    }

    $newAccount = $account;
    echo 'New account: ' . $account . PHP_EOL;
});
```

See more: https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php#assign-value-to-outside-scopefrom-callback-scope-to-outside-scope

Comment: For the record, it is not an HD wallet (if you are searching for it)

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum uses [`ECC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography) (Elliptic Curve Cryptography) with the [`secp256k1`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) curve. The signature algorithm is [`ECDSA`](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_digital_signature_algorithm).

Now a good tool I would recommend for `js` is [`Ethers`](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/). It has a complete toolset for creating keypairs with mnemonics, recover, sign transactions, sign messages ...

For non-Ethereum `ECC` libraries it might not work right out of the box; Ethereum signatures include `network id` to prevent replay attacks, so you might have to adapt some things before it could work 100%.